# Empty dataframe with ust column headers

Tags: python, excel, web, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape data from the IMDB website with the following lines of code but I got an empty dataframe with just the column headers after importing the file:

```py
excel = openpyxl.Workbook() # Creating an excel workbook where the data will be saved
sheet = excel.active
sheet.title = 'Top Rated Movies' # naming the sheet
sheet.append(['rank', 'title', 'year', 'rating']) # naming the column headers


try:
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
    }
    source = requests.get('https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/', headers=headers)
    source.raise_for_status() 
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source.content, 'html.parser') 
    
    movies = soup.find_all('tr')
    for movie in movies[1:]:  # Skip the first row (header)
        cells = movie.find_all('td')
        rank = cells[0].text.strip()
        title = cells[1].find('a').text.strip()
        year = cells[1].find('span', class_='secondaryInfo').text.strip('()')
        rating = cells[2].text.strip()
        
        print(f"Rank: {rank}, Title: {title}, Year: {year}, Rating: {rating}")
        
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

    
excel.save('IMDB Movie Ratings.xlsx')
```

Comment: The instruction `soup.find('tbody', class_ = 'lister-list')` return `None`

Answer (score 1):

This should work. I grabbed each movie tile by class name and then stripped its content down using regEx.

```js
import requests,re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
try:
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
    }
    source = requests.get('https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/', headers=headers)
    source.raise_for_status() 
    html_pattern = r'<[^>]+>'

    soup = BeautifulSoup(source.content, 'html.parser') 
    movies = soup.find_all('li', {'class':'ipc-metadata-list-summary-item sc-59b6048d-0 jemTre cli-parent'})
    
    for movie in movies:
        children = ''.join([str(item) for item in movie.children])
        text_only = [item for item in re.sub(html_pattern, ', ', children).split(', ') if item != '']
        title = ' '.join(text_only[0].split(' ')[1:])
        rank =  text_only[0].split(' ')[0][:-1]
        year = text_only[1]
        duration = text_only[2]
        rating = text_only[4]
        print(f"Rank: {rank}, Title: {title}, Year: {year}, Rating: {rating}")
    
        
        
        
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: Thanks so much @skxxtz. It worked very well this time.

Answer (score 0):

As said by @frankfalse, `soup.find` returns `None`. This is because it is looking for a tag / class couple that does not exist. If you press F12 and inspect element on the URL you provided, you'll see that what you are looking for is `h3/ipc-title__text`:

```py
movies = soup.find_all("h3", class_="ipc-title__text")
for movie in movies:
    print(movie)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The line of code you proposed worked just fine. But I have modified the code again, then ran it, his time the output is an empty dataframe with just the column headers. The code is here: